# Php:ingres equivalent of mysql_insert_id()

Tags: php, ingres

I've to make some PHP interaction with an Ingres database. I need to get the ID of the last entry I inserted in the database.

How should I proceed? I'm not an ingres expert, but I suppose there is also auto-incremented ID/Sequences/...?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `last_identity()` function will give you the last generated sequence number for a table, e.g.:

```
SELECT last_identity() FROM t1
```

From what I understand the sequence number needs to be created, using `CREATE TABLE` using the following syntax:

```
colname integer generated always as identity
```

e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 ( 
    idx integer generated always as identity,
    sometext varchar(100) not null
)
```

See http://community.ingres.com/wiki/Using_Ingres_Identity_Columns for some additional notes on using identity columns.

Comment: But, it will be done a second request no?

What if we have a code which insert and ask the last id, but with concurrency we can have this:
UserA insert object 1
UserB insert object 2
UserA ask for the last ID and receive the ID ???(1 or 2 here?)
UserB ask for the last ID and receive the ID 2

This is dangerous, no?

Comment: It's my understanding that the value comes from the session not from a table. See http://community.ingres.com/wiki/New_Ingres_10_Functions#LAST_IDENTITY_function.

Comment: Okay thank you! But I'm experiencing some troubles when trying to create the table. For which version of ingres does this work? Because I've the 9.2

Comment: Okay, but it appears that the generated always as identity doesn't work with the 9.2, we have to use sequences with the 9.2

Comment: Then `SELECT sequence_name.currval` should work but you have to know the name of the sequence for each table/column you're using. See http://docs.ingres.com/ingres/9.3/sql-reference-guide/4859-next-value-for-current-value-for